# Custom user role still showing up after deletion, ideas?

Tags: functions, user-roles, users

I previously created a new user role called "Owner" which worked fine, however I decided to delete it afterwards from my functions.php since I found it to not be as useful for my project after all...Odd thing is though, the new custom user role is still showing up in wordpress' dropdown menu where you assign a role to a user in the dashboard.

Any ideas whats going on here? 
I double checked my functions.php over and over and I deleted the function for sure so I have no ideas whats going on...My guess is its getting cached somehow but clearing the browser out makes no difference.

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running this once in your `functions.php`

```
   $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
   $wp_roles->remove_role("your_role");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take look in your database, view your wp_site_options table, find roles, and just see what the heck is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I couldnt identify the problem in my database so I tried running the removal script and that seemed to do it.